# Safari web browser dropping cookies and session timing out

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, nopcommerce

I have an issue with a web application launching a method when using safari web browser,

The method launches fine when using other web browsers and when third party cookies acceptance is enabled in Safari,

When third party cookies are blocked the session times out and instead launches a login screen

Has anyone seen this issue before or has any ideas to a solution ?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information on the specific problem. Does your app require 3rd party cookies? Which cookies specifically are being dropped? Any example code to demonstrate the issue so someone can replicate it?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, it's an issue with cross domain cookies which has been covered before on here.

The solution I find is to get the user to visit the site that I want to punchout to first from the parent site. I did this by the form of a popup that instantly closes, this then leaves a cookie for the punchout site and then it therefore works in the iframe